# When can I make another charge to my charge card?

Tags: american-express

I have an American Express Platinum Card with the credit limit. I pay my bill every month in full. I had an unexpected expense pop up. But I am up to my limit on my American Express. This is closing date the 14th. When will I be able to charge again?

Comment: Isn't Amex Platinum a charge card?

Comment: Will you not be able to pay the balance before the closing date?  If not you'll get hit with late fees and interest that you'll need to pay off before you can pay down enough principal to charge again.

Comment: Yes it is a charge card the closing date changes

Comment: @RachelBrinkhoff I don't own one but I believe charge card does not have an explicit limit.

Comment: Call American Express.  You're a Platinum member, they will be very nice to you.  Amex has some thing called pay over time for charge card holders, where I think they let you roll part of your balance in to a credit facility freeing up your charge card for regular activities. Call and talk to them.

Comment: @quid is correct here. Call American Express and talk to them. For extraordinary expenses they should be willing to temporarily up the limit for you. Their customer service is outstanding and easy to work with.

Comment: It is a misconception that charge cards have "no limit". True that there isn't a limit in writing, however, that means that you could have a "limit" of a dollar or a million dollars.

Comment: @DStanley - closing date means the bill hasn't been cut yet, no late fee, no interest. 14th me and current charges won't bo due till 5/7 soonest.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: **When will I be able to charge again?**

After you pay your bill, then you'll be able to charge again. But as the comments have pointed out, if you call American Express, assuming you have had a good relationship with them, they should be able to approve a transaction if you let them know ahead of time (even if it's 10 minutes) and the amount.